# Converting very large files from xml to csv

Tags: c#, xml, csv, converters, large-files

Currently I'm using the following code snippet to convert a `.txt` file with `XML` data to `.CSV` format. My question is this, currently this works perfectly with files that are around 100-200 mbs and the conversion time is very low (1-2 minutes max), However I now need this to work for much bigger files (1-2 GB's each file). Currently the program freezes the computer and the conversion takes about 30-40 minutes with this function. Not sure how I would proceed changing this function. Any help will be appreciated!

```
    string all_lines = File.ReadAllText(p);

    all_lines = "<Root>" + all_lines + "</Root>";
    XmlDocument doc_all = new XmlDocument();
    doc_all.LoadXml(all_lines);
    StreamWriter write_all = new StreamWriter(FILENAME1);
    XmlNodeList rows_all = doc_all.GetElementsByTagName("XML");

    foreach (XmlNode rowtemp in rows_all)
    {
        List<string> children_all = new List<string>();
        foreach (XmlNode childtemp in rowtemp.ChildNodes)
        {
            children_all.Add(Regex.Replace(childtemp.InnerText, "\\s+", " "));             
        }
        write_all.WriteLine(string.Join(",", children_all.ToArray()));
    }
    write_all.Flush();
    write_all.Close();
```

Sample Input::

```
 <XML><DSTATUS>1,4,7,,5</DSTATUS><EVENT> hello,there,my,name,is,jack,</EVENT>
     last,name,missing,above <ANOTHERTAG>3,6,7,,8,4</ANOTHERTAG> </XML>

 <XML><DSTATUS>1,5,7,,3</DSTATUS><EVENT>hello,there,my,name,is,mary,jane</EVENT>
     last,name,not,missing,above<ANOTHERTAG>3,6,7,,8,4</ANOTHERTAG></XML>
```

Sample Output::

```
1,4,7,,5,hello,there,my,name,is,jack,,last,name,missing,above,3,6,7,,8,4
1,5,7,,3,hello,there,my,name,is,mary,jane,last,name,not,missing,above,3,6,7,,8,4
```

Comment: You want to parse a 2Gb file. It's going to take time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The most efficient way to parse Xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/606304/the-most-efficient-way-to-parse-xml)

Comment: Looking at sample input and output I'd say read it line by line **as text** and write everything except tags (`<` + text inside + `>`). Should be fastest way. Based on your last comment, concatenate lines until result contains `</xml>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to take a streaming approach, as you're currently reading the entire 2Gb file into memory and then processing it.  You should read a bit of XML, write a bit of CSV and keep doing that until you've processed it all.

A possible solution is below:

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(FILENAME1))
{
    foreach (var element in StreamElements(r, "XML"))
    {
        var values = element.DescendantNodes()
            .OfType<XText>()
            .Select(e => Regex.Replace(e.Value, "\\s+", " "));

        var line = string.Join(",", values);

        writer.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

Where `StreamElements` is inspired by Jon Skeet's streaming of `XElement`s from an `XmlReader` in an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441673/reading-xml-with-xmlreader-in-c-sharp).  I've made some changes to support your 'invalid' XML (as you have no root element):

```
private static IEnumerable<XElement> StreamElements(string fileName, string elementName)
{
    var settings = new XmlReaderSettings
    {
        ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment
    };

    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(fileName, settings))
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
            {
                if (reader.Name == elementName)
                {
                    var el = XNode.ReadFrom(reader) as XElement;
                    if (el != null)
                    {
                        yield return el;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just tested this, it is significantly faster in reading and writing, however the output is just 1 single line. Basically all the data in csv format together.

Comment: @sparta93 I've made a few edits since I first wrote it - check what you have matches what's there now.  Specifically, it originally said `writer.Write` instead of `writer.WriteLine`.  I've also removed another line from `StreamElements` that would cause you to miss the first line in your XML.

Comment: No problem.  I'd be interested to know the timing difference with this vs what you had before (I'm too lazy to try and create a 200Mb and 2Gb XML file!).

Comment: For a 1 GB .txt file with xml data, my old method took around ~25-30 minutes, this method takes ~45 seconds. What a change in performance!

Comment: Actually I just noticed something in the outputs, for lines in the input that are in the following format <xml><header>1,3,4,5,,</header>2,5,6,7</xml>, the output is only 1,3,4,5,, for that line. It skips everything after </header>. Any idea whats causing this?

Comment: OK, that's a little different.  That's what's known as 'mixed content' where an element contains text as well as other elements.  I'll update the answer to just return all text nodes within the element.  I'm impressed by the performance difference!

Answer (score 2):

If you're prepared to consider a completely different way of doing it, download Saxon-EE 9.6, get an evaluation license, and run the following streaming XSLT 3.0 code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template name="main">
  <xsl:stream href="input.xml">
    <xsl:for-each select="*/*">
       <xsl:value-of select="*!normalize-space()" separator=","/>
       <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:stream>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

It freezes because of `File.ReadAllText(p);`

Do not read the complete file into memory. (This will first start swapping, then halt your CPU because no more memory is available)

Use a chunking approach: Read line by line, convert line by line, write line by line.

Use some lower level XML Reader class, not `XmlDocument`

Comment: Each input (from <XML> to </XML> can span either one line or multiple lines. I'm not sure what to use and how...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/606304/the-most-efficient-way-to-parse-xml for some details.

Answer (score -2):

There are two variants. First is to hide program-freeze, use BackgroundWorker for it.
Second: read your text file string-by-string, use any Reader for it (Xml or any text\file).
You can combine these variants.

Comment: This does not contain anywhere near enough detail. *use any reader* is also totally wrong, [each reader has pro's and con's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/606332/542251) if your looking for efficiency you need to choose your reader carefully